# Sinatra app being run by user 'nobody' in shared folder on VM

Tags: sinatra, windows-8.1, virtual-machine, virtualbox, shared-directory

I have a folder on my host OS (Windows 8.1) which is set up as a shared folder with VirtualBox (running Ubuntu 14.04 Server). The shared folder is set up correctly, but is giving me problems regarding permissions when I try to run apps which are inside of it.

All the files in the shared folder are owned by root and the group vboxsf. I have added my current user and the Apache user to the vboxsf group using the following commands:

```
sudo adduser cornflakes24 vboxsf
sudo adduser www-data vboxsf
```

However, when I visit my web browser to test the app, I am greeted with the following error:

> This web application process is being run as user 'nobody' and group
>   'nogroup' and must be able to access its application root directory
>   '/var/www/html/webdev/ruby'. However, the parent directory
>   '/var/www/html/webdev' has wrong permissions, thereby preventing this
>   process from accessing its application root directory. Please fix the
>   permissions of the directory '/var/www/html/webdev' first.

The webdev folder in reference above is actually a symlink:

`lrwxrwxrwx cornflakes24 www-data webdev -> /media/sf_webdev`.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Can you provide current permission of `/media/sf_webdev/`? Why your application runs as `nobody`? May be you should run it as `www-data`?

Comment: I did give the permission of `/media/sf_webdev/`; please see the second last line of my question (user is me, group is www-data, and both have full 777 permissions). And yes, clearly I want the app run by the Apache daemon user (www-data). I was able to get some apps running by using the ruby provided server (and I have also tried rails server) and it's painfully slow - so maybe this is a lost cause.